# Как можно вывести меню?

Tags: php

Пишу небольшой сервис, и возникла проблема с меню.

Html код меню:

```
<div class="span3 box"><p class="box-header">Меню</p>
<li class="menu-link"><a href="ссылка">текст</a></li>
<li class="menu-link"><a href="ссылка">текст</a></li>
...
```

Для более простого вывода ссылок написал небольшую функцию:

```
Body::create()
->AddMenu()
->AddMenuLink('Заголовок','ссылка')
```

И при создании других разделов сайта, необходимо заново вводить этот код, но можно ли как-то это упростить?

Comment: А как "небольшая функция" соотносится с "Html код меню"?

Comment: А что мешает создать функцию, скажем, `BuildMenu()`, в которую внести Ваш код. А потом вызывать эту функцию там, где надо?

Comment: А как мне в эту функцию вносить новые элементы из админки?